# Using a MotionController Component in Unreal with C++ instead of Blueprint

Tags: c++, virtual-reality, unreal-engine4, oculus

After iterating through an array of `FMotionControllerSource` of an OculusInputDevice `IMotionController`, I found a connected Oculus Right and Left Touch Controller based on it's ETrackingStatus. With the left and right controllers, I can get the location and rotation using the `IMotionController` API, which `Returns the calibration-space orientation of the requested controller's hand`.

Here's a reference to the IMotionController API:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/HeadMountedDisplay/IMotionController/index.html

I want to apply the location/rotation to a `PosableMesh`, so that the mesh is shown where the Oculus controller is in reality. Currently, with the code below the 3D model is displayed down from the camera, so the mapping scale is off. I think `WorldToMetersScale`might be off. When I use a small number the controller doesn't move the 3D model much, but this might be messing it up.

```
            FVector position;
            FRotator rotation;
            int id = tracker.deviceIndex;
            FName srcName = tracker.motionControllerSource;
            bool success = tracker.motionController->GetControllerOrientationAndPosition(id, srcName, rotation, position, 250.0f);
            if (success)
            {
                poseMesh->SetWorldLocationAndRotation(position, rotation);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the camera position to the controller position seemed to fix the issue:

```
// get camera reference during BeginPlay:
camManager = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->PlayerCameraManager;

// TickComponent
poseMesh->SetWorldLocationAndRotation(camManager->GetCameraLocation() + position, rotation);
```